# Oddity with `NOT IN` in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I needed to query for customers in one table that are not present in another table. I started with this query using NOT IN with a subquery, which yielded no results.

```
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerEmail 
FROM New_Customers
WHERE CustomerEmail NOT IN 
(SELECT CustomerEmail FROM Customers)
```

I then switched to using a LEFT JOIN, which returned what I believe to be the correct results.

```
SELECT n.CustomerName, n.CustomerEmail
FROM New_Customers n 
LEFT JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerEmail = n.CustomerEmail
WHERE c.CustomerName IS NULL
```

I'm wondering why the first query did not return any results? I'll add that my dataset is rather large (Customers table contains 94,699 rows).

Comment: `SELECT CustomerEmail FROM Customers` contains a `NULL` so it doesn't match anything, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516011/14868997 Instead use `NOT EXISTS` eg `SELECT nc.CustomerName, nc.CustomerEmail 
FROM New_Customers nc WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customers c WHERE c.CustomerEmail = nc.CustomerEmail)`

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I didn't realize there were two rows with null values.